# Optimize repeteted queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have few querysets that I use in every single view (>50). Is there a way to write once for all and keep the queryset result available for all views ?

```
def MyView(request):
company= Company.objects.get(User=request.user)
user_info= User_infos.objects.get(User= request.user)
groups= request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat = True)
```

I'm using those results for filtering purposes like

```
Product.objects.filter(Company = company)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/), this can allow repeated querysets to be kept for a set amount of time and then instead of querying it will get the cached results.

Comment: queryset result is different for each user. I thought caching can be do only if the resul is common to all users ?

Comment: how many entries do these tables have approximately, as you could cache all entries then filter them per user when rendering them

Comment: Yes can be but in term of performance doesn't be the same as querying again ?

Comment: Company.objects.get(User=request.user) vs Company_cache.filter(User=request.user)

Comment: a filter would add a hit but if the data is cached it means there is no sql queries, just the filter which will speed up compared to multiple filters and queries

Comment: I will study this and make some tests, thank you

Comment: hope i could help, also i recommend [django-cachalot](https://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), i use it and it works great :)